# Getting invalid_grant error while generating access token using Laravel\Passport

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-passport

I am using laravel 8.40 and passport 10.3. I want to generate token without authorization. for that I have followed the laravel passport documentation. But when I try to generate token using the following sippent

```
grant_type:password
client_id:959f0346-0848-4aca-af63-ed77daba2561
client_secret:lLSI6Yg4RRh5ZaH00fAaVhcU9C5Zd8ITfe9XTO8H
username:admin@test.com
password:password
scope:*
```

though my credentials are correct I test on my web guard, I am getting this response

```
 {
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "The user credentials were incorrect.",
    "message": "The user credentials were incorrect."
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace

```
"grant_type":password
```

to

```
"grant_type":client_credentials
```